# Question about the ROS2 Metrics on metrics.ros.org

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I was looking at the metrics report for ROS2 the other day, found [here](https://metrics.ros.org/packages_ros2.html), and I was wondering if someone could clarify this chart for me. In the chart, we see that Windows is the largest OS section for Dashing, Eloquent, and Foxy releases. Does this mean that users are downloading the binaries to run ROS2 on Windows OR does this mean that users are downloading ROS2 on Windows devices, but not necessarily running ROS on Windows itself (using VMs or something of that sort to run ROS on Linux instead). My guess is the latter since most ROS users are Linux users, but I just wanted to make sure.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/392854/question-about-the-ros2-metrics-on-metrics.ros.org/) by [yujinkim](https://answers.ros.org/users/84820/yujinkim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2021-12-15

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-12-15**:
Not sure but thank you for asking. I wouldn’t be surprised is Windows users using Visual Studio. The installation is a lot smoother now as well and documentation is also better than in ROS1

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-12-15**:
@David Lu when you have a chance can you let us know how this is calculated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The metrics site parses apache/nginx web server logs directly. Those contain the web browser's user agent, which contains an identifying string which states the OS on which the browser is running.

Whether you're running an OS in a VM or bare metal does not matter: the browser will report what the user agent says, which by default mentions the OS the browser is running on.

And technically there is no way to know for certain whether people are using Windows to download `.deb`s and then taking those to their Ubuntu PC or VM, or the other way around (download on Linux, install on Windows). It's all possible.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-12-16**:
Thank you @gvdhoorn, it's very interesting data.